# Highlight Duplicates between two ranges on different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, highlight

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to highlight duplicate cells between two ranges on different worksheets. The code below is painfully slow:

```
    Sub HighlightDuplicates()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

lrU = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lrPT = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng1, rng2, cell1, cell2 As Range

Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("DL4:DL" & lrU)
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E3:M" & lrPT)

    For Each cell1 In rng1

        For Each cell2 In rng2

            If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then

            cell1.Font.Bold = True
            cell1.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            cell1.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            cell2.Font.Bold = True
            cell2.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            cell2.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid

            End If

        Next cell2
     Next cell1
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Any suggestions on a more efficient method?

Thanks for any help.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried conditional formatting?

Comment: Try also adding `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating=false at the top and 1Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic` and `Application.ScreenUpdating=true` at the bottom.

Comment: If you want efficient, you'll likely need to avoid VBA and just use straight formulas (or as Kyle mentioned formatting).  I usually use a formula (ie `MATCH`) in a column on one sheet I dedicate for it ...

Comment: Also consider using the `Find` method. You could loop through just one range and try to find each value in the other range using the `Find` method. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Comment: Further to @Kyle's comment, is conditional formatting not an option? It's probably a little quicker, and wouldn't require a macro/VB.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Is it possible to apply conditional formatting on ranges of different shapes (i.e. one range may be one column but the other range may be several columns)?

Answer (score 1):

Putting my comments together, you could modify your code to look something like this (untested)

```
Sub HighlightDuplicates()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
application.calculation=xlcalculationmanual
application.screenupdating=false

lrU = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lrPT = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng1, rng2, cell1, cell2 As Range

Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("DL4:DL" & lrU)
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E3:M" & lrPT)

For Each cell2 In rng2
    Set cell1 = rng1.Find(cell2, lookin:=xlValues)
    if not cell1 is nothing then
        firstAddress = cell1.address
        Do
            cell1.Font.Bold = True
            cell1.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            cell1.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            cell2.Font.Bold = True
            cell2.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            cell2.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            Set cell1 = rng1.FindNext(cell2)
        Loop While Not cell1 Is Nothing And cell1.Address <> firstAddress 
    end if
next cell1

application.displayalerts=true
application.calculation=xlcalculationmanual
application.screenupdating=true
end sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I think the amount of cells I  have in each range maybe too much for excel to handle. Everything runs, but it still takes around 5 minutes.

Comment: So my code worked, but it took 5 minutes. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, it is. Which is about the same length of time my macro takes.

Comment: It looks like `rng2` is the larger of the two ranges. Maybe loop through `rng1` and do your find on `rng2`.